# How to compile a file using a shared library?

Tags: gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a source given a .so file `libfoo.so`. The only thing in this library is a function that just returns a number (yeah, I know, advanced stuff). The header file equivalent (I was provided with both, but am only supposed to use the .so) is named `foo.h` and the function is named `int foo()`.

My source file is `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    int x = foo();

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;   
}
```

Now, when trying to compile I have the following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c main.c -o main.o

gcc -Wall -fPIC main.o -o main -lfoo -L.
```

The first command fails to create the object file, outputting the following error:

```
fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I have also tried exporting the current location to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as I've seen suggested on a few other answers.

```
export LD_LBIRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:machine/Desktop/lib_test
```

Comment: Where is `foo.h` located and what are you doing to tell your compiler where to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the interface definition from the `.h` file and that file **must** be in the current directory or a directory on the include search path.

Note that on some systems filenames and paths are case dependent.